# Python multiply game. My script needs to have a arbitrarily number of players that each have to take turn in answering a multiplication question

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, while-loop

Basically i need to make a game im python that can have a arbitrarily number of people that alternatly answers a multiplication question. But my issue is that i dont know how to keep it running until i hit 30 points. Ive tried to use dict's where the key is the player name and the value is the score. But it stops after the script only has ran once. I tried with a while loop but it went on forever. please help!

```
import random as r

n = int(input("Insert number of players: "))
d = {}

for i in range(n):
    keys = input("Insert player name: ")
#to set the score to 0
    values = 0
    d[keys] = values
#to display player names
print("Player names are:")
for key in d:
    print(key)

for value in d.values():
    if value < 30:
        random1 = r.randint(0,9)
        random2 = r.randint(0,9)
        
        print(f"The two numbers you should multiplie is {random1} and {random2}")

        correct = random1*random2
        user_inp = input("Insert answer: ")
        user_inp = int(user_inp)
        if user_inp == correct:
            print("Correct!")
            d[keys] += 1
        else:
            print("Wrong!")
            d[keys] -= 2
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
    winner = False
    while not winner :
        for value in d.values():
            if value < 30:
                random1 = r.randint(0,9)
                random2 = r.randint(0,9)
                
                print(f"The two numbers you should multiplie is {random1} and {random2}")
    
                correct = random1*random2
                user_inp = input("Insert answer: ")
                user_inp = int(user_inp)
                if user_inp == correct:
                    print("Correct!")
                    d[keys] += 1
                else:
                    print("Wrong!")
                    d[keys] -= 2
            else:
                winner = True
                break
```

Comment: i tried this, and it doesnt stop when the player hit ex. 30 points?